# tmux не видит открытые сессии

Tags: java, linux, minecraft, tmux

Я использую putty для подключению к серверу, на сервере стоит oracle linux 8.5. Я создаю сессию `tmux -S server` и запускаю там сервер Майнкрафт джава. Потом я выхожу из putty. При следуещем входе я ввожу `tmux ls` но мне выводитсься это:

> no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default

Я пробывал подключиться к сессии `tmux a -t server`, но мне пишет:

> no session

Пожалуйста помогите

Comment: дык, `tmux -S server ls`... и в принципе, зачем ты указываешь свой сокет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось. Сессию надо создавать так `tmux new-session -t НАЗВАНИЕ -d`  , также перед тем как выйти с putty надо выйти из сессии нажимая <ctrl+b> d или `tmux detach` . `tmux ls` работает как надо. Для входа в сессию `tmux a -t НАЗВАНИЕ`